# How to make a completely invisible sprite in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm developing a my first videogame in Pygame (Python), something similar to Space Invaders.
The enemies need to move syncronized, in order to get it I created a sprite.

Why a sprite?
To use the update() method to move it. The enemies will adjust their positions depending on this invisible box sprite (EnemyBox) by readind its updated rect variable.

But...
I get this message when I try to run it:
AttributeError: 'EnemyBox' object has no attribute 'image'

Questions:
is there a way to get a completely invisible sprite?
do you think there is a better mecanism to make all enemies move syncronizly?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a EnemyBox, you don't have to use a Sprite for this.

You can create your own class that will have a Rect attribute.

Something along the lines:

```
class EnemyBox:
    def __init__(self):
        self.rect = Rect(0,0,50,50)
    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(5,0)
```

You can have an invisible sprite, but you still need an image assigned to it. Look up [Dirty Sprite](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.DirtySprite)